# Water coming out of a vertical tube lifts a weight to a certain height

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Before I even start the question I would like to apologize in advance for some grammar mistakes since I translated this question from another language.

Water is coming out of a vertical tube at a velocity of $V=10\;\mathrm{m/s}$. The cross-section of the tube is $8\;\mathrm{cm^2}$. The water hits a weight with a mass of $2\;\mathrm{kg}$ and the weight is being held at a certain height. Calculate that height.

This is what I tried

$$
\frac{1}{2}M_vV^2 = M_vgh + M_wgh
$$
where $M_v$ is the mass of water, $M_w$ is the mass of the weight and $h$ is the height that I had to calculate.

And $M_v$= $ρ*s*h$

Where $ρ$ is the water density and $s$ is the cross-section.

I found this problem in a Bosnian physics book and I have the final result but not the step-by-step solution.

Comment: Welcome to Ph SE. As this is clearly a homework question please show your own effort.

Comment: Hi Mirza and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I figured I would post here since this is a problem i found while preparing for a physics contest (or olympiad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try and point you in the right direction but as this is homework you'll have to put in some effort too.

[image: Situation diagram.]

Although an exact solution would be difficult to arrive at, an approximate one can be obtained using Bernoulli's Equation:

$$\frac{v_1^2}{2}+gz_1+\frac{p_1}{\rho}=\frac{v_2^2}{2}+gz_2+\frac{p_2}{\rho}$$

Obviously the problem is to find $\Delta z=z_2-z_1$. To do so we need to make a few approximations.

Firstly, as the water bounces off the weight in *all directions*, I'll assume:

$$v_1 \gg v_2$$

So we can neglect $v_2$.

Then we need values for $p_1$ and $p_2$. Obviously $p_1$ is simply atmospheric pressure.

For $p_2$ I'll assume:

$$p_2 \approx \frac{mg}{A}+p_1$$

Plug it all in:

$$\frac{v_1^2}{2}+gz_1+\frac{p_1}{\rho}\approx gz_2+\frac{mg}{\rho A}+\frac{p_1}{\rho}$$

Reworked:

$$\Delta z \approx \frac{1}{g}\big(\frac{v_1^2}{2}-\frac{mg}{\rho A}\big)$$

Now you need to plug in the numbers (respect SI measuring units!) and calculate $\Delta z$.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I got the same result with my approach, and I am absolutely sure yours is correct so I am going to email the author of the book and hope he responds since his result is 2m and the result I got after calculating both times is 2.6m

Comment: Thank you! The approach is correct but nonetheless approximate. No friction is accounted for, for example.